# Removing data in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains the price of a ticker like this:

```
date                    price
2006-01-02 09:00:00     6548.34
2006-01-02 09:01:00     6457.61
2006-01-02 09:02:00     6452.82
2006-01-02 09:03:00     6452.39
2006-01-02 09:04:00     6451.61
                         ...
2021-01-29 13:29:40    15229.54
2021-01-29 13:29:45    15229.54
2021-01-29 13:29:50    15229.54
2021-01-29 13:29:55    15229.54
2021-01-29 13:30:00    15138.31
```

How can I remove the hour, minute, and second parts in the date?

I mean I want something like this.

```
date          price
2006-01-02    6577.33
2006-01-03    6488.62
2006-01-04    6469.82
2006-01-05    6555.39
2006-01-06    6448.65
                         ...
2021-01-25    15229.53
2021-01-26    15129.34
2021-01-27    14129.64
2021-01-28    15228.34
2021-01-29    15138.31
```

I only want the last price of each day.

So the thing I want to do is to remove all the other prices of each day.

How can I achieve this?

My `df.index` returns the following

```
>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2006-01-02 09:00:00', '2006-01-02 09:01:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:02:00', '2006-01-02 09:03:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:04:00', '2006-01-02 09:05:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:06:00', '2006-01-02 09:07:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:08:00', '2006-01-02 09:09:00',
               ...
               '2021-01-29 13:29:15', '2021-01-29 13:29:20',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:25', '2021-01-29 13:29:30',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:35', '2021-01-29 13:29:40',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:45', '2021-01-29 13:29:50',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:55', '2021-01-29 13:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=6345485, freq=None)
```

`df.columns` returns

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['price'], dtype='object', name='stock_id')
```

My `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d')` returns

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2006-01-02 09:00:00', '2006-01-02 09:01:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:02:00', '2006-01-02 09:03:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:04:00', '2006-01-02 09:05:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:06:00', '2006-01-02 09:07:00',
               '2006-01-02 09:08:00', '2006-01-02 09:09:00',
               ...
               '2021-01-29 13:29:15', '2021-01-29 13:29:20',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:25', '2021-01-29 13:29:30',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:35', '2021-01-29 13:29:40',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:45', '2021-01-29 13:29:50',
               '2021-01-29 13:29:55', '2021-01-29 13:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=6345485, freq=None)
```

This is so strange. Because the `to_datetime()` conversion doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep only the date of the datetime, and then group by the date and keeping the last value of each:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.normalize()
df = df.groupby("date").last("price")
```

I added `pd.to_datetime()` if your date is not in the datetime format.

Comment: Don't use `dt.date` in Pandas dataframe. They are treated as `object` dtype and do not play well with many other Pandas' functions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I changed `dt.date` to `dt.nomalize()`.

Comment: @XavierBrt. Thank you for replying. But the format of my DataFrame seems to be different than yours. 
Do you know how to convert in my case?

Comment: I've added my DataFrame format in my post.

Comment: Ok, your `date` already had the `datetime` format so `pd.to_datetime()` was not necessary, as you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to XavierBrt's answer, I've figured out the conversion for the format of my DataFrame.

```
df.index = df.index.normalize()
df = df.groupby(df.index).last('price')
```